# How to choose which character encoding to use?

Tags: python, character-encoding

In Python, using `subprocess.Popen` we often have to convert the output of an external tool from bytes to string.  I have always used UTF-8 for this without thinking much about it, and I haven't had a problem so far.  I came across some code where someone is using ASCII instead, and this got me thinking how should I know which encoding to use and does it matter?

For simple strings, it doesn't seem to make a difference, for example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'], encoding='ASCII')
'4091146\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'], encoding='utf-8')
'4091146\n'
```

I understand that UTF-8 is a larger character set, so "special" characters cannot be encoded as ASCII:

```
>>> "Büster".encode('utf-8')
b'B\xc3\xbcster'
>>> "Büster".encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I guess the encoding depends on the external program, so how can I know which one to use?  Is it safe to just always assume UTF-8?

Answer (score 5):

There is no "one size fits all" answer. What makes sense on your system doesn't make sense for other systems. (Python should trivially support only a single encoding if this wasn't the case, don't you think?)

On any computer, the main consideration is to remain compatible with other utilities on the system. If your system is a "big iron" mainframe from the dark ages, probably everything needs to be configured to use some horrible legacy 8-bit encoding (or worse!) At the other end of the spectrum, the world is moving towards Unicode and specifically the UTF-8 encoding (see also https://utf8everywhere.org/); if you are using a reasonably modern non-Windows system, your `locale` will probably indicate that the system is set up for UTF-8, and then that's what you should use (and what Python is almost certainly already configured to use as its default encoding; so you really just need to say `text=True` and not explicitly name an encoding).

That leaves Windows, which *commonly* is configured with whatever code page makes sense for the geography where it was sold; in the Americas and Western Europe, that means code page 1252, while in other parts of the world it means something else (Eastern Europe 1250 or 1251, various other country- or region-specific code pages in various other parts of the world); but again, with `subprocess` you can get away with just `text=True` and have Python choose on your behalf.

The keyword argument `text=True` was previously called `universal_newlines=True` which still works; really old Python 3 versions will still require you to explicitly encode and decode, and of course there are situations where you need or want to use raw binary encoding to communicate with selected external utilities.

Examples:

```py
r = subprocess.run(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'],
    text=True, capture_output=True)
print(r.stdout)  # implicitly uses Python's default encoding to decode

s = subprocess.run(['dd', 'if=/dev/urandom', 'bs=32', 'count=1'],
    capture_output=True)
random_bytes = s.stdout  # not text, no encoding, just raw bytes

# Actually don't use Popen when run() can do the job
fugly = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/etc/motd'], text=True)
stdout, stderr = fugly.communicate()
fugly.wait()  # really, use subprocess.run() instead

# If you specifically want a particular encoding, of course, go for it
weird = subprocess.run(['iconv', '-t', 'koi8-u'],
    stdin=open('utf8.txt'), encoding='koi8-u', capture_output=True)
```

(`subprocess.run()` replaces `check_output` and friends, though you can of course still use them for convenience. Most of these examples are really tortured anyway, and you should really use Python's native functionality instead of an external subprocess.)

On systems which are in the middle of a migration, you really have to check individually for each utility which encoding it requires, though for UTF-8 it's conveniently transparent, and so many utilities which were never explicitly adapted to UTF-8 will simply continue to work.  The problem areas will be collation (sort order) and corner cases like Unicode normalization (a naïve string comparison will not regard the sequence U+006F U+0308 as equivalent to the code point U+00F6 even though they both represent the single glyph **ö**).

Communication over a network can be troublesome. For HTTP, ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin-1) was codified as the standard character set for HTML for a while, though it is now UTF-8. For many network protocols, it is unspecified, and you just have to experiment. Modern protocols which involve textual information should specify an encoding or a mechanism for explicitly tagging the character set and encoding of any textual data; the MIME headers were originally specified for email, but have made their way to several other protocols, including HTTP. Email has a confusing array of additional encodings to enable complete transparency over a channel which used to only support 7-bit ASCII; notice how message bodies, message headers, and file name attributes in MIME headers each have their own mechanism for this. (RFCs 2045, 2047, and 2231.)

Comment: Really useful answer, thanks. But could be made even better if you give an example of how you would use `text=True`. For example, if using `Popen`, would it be used on the `Popen` call on a subsequent call such as `communicate`? And would it cause a method that would otherwise return bytes to return a string instead?

Comment: Thanks, I added a few examples. Yes, subprocesses send and receive bytes in Python 3 unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any encoding which will always be safe to use -- you will need to match it to the encoding which will have been used for any strings in the output of the external command.

Here for example, is an attempt to use utf-8 to decode a Cyrillic string in koi8-r encoding.

```
>>> name
b'\xed\xc9\xc8\xc1\xc9\xcc'

>>> name.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte

>>> name.decode('koi8-r')
'Михаил'
```

I suppose that if you wanted to convert an object of type bytes into one of type string in a way that is guaranteed not to raise an exception, you could simply call `str` on it, and maybe discard the leading `b'` and trailing `'`.  Such an approach would give the same value as decoding it for simple ASCII strings.

```
>>> name2
b'Michael'

>>> str(name2)[2:-1]
'Michael'
```

However, of course, it will not give anything like the intended characters for anything else.  Here is our friend Михаил again.

```
>>> str(name)[2:-1]
'\\xed\\xc9\\xc8\\xc1\\xc9\\xcc'
```

(Note: the double backslashes are just part of the implied `repr` output here. The string itself contains single backslashes, as `print` would show.)

Comment: UTF-8 *is* a universal encoding, though it's not - yet - the universal standard, and obviously also not the only encoding for the universal character set Unicode.

Comment: Actually I just deleted the word "universal". Obviously you're right in the sense that it is intended to be used to represent any character. I guess I just meant "that can be used in all situations", but I made it more confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Most external programs use `latin-1` which is the same as `iso-8859-1`.  Every byte is converted into a single character by putting zeroes in the high bits.

Comment: Both sentences are untrue and the second is weird.

Comment: @triplee: In what way are both sentences untrue?  In my experience, most programs output ISO-8859-1?  If, as per the original example, the program outputs 0xFC for ü and that's the end of it.  

And latin-1 is the same as iso-8859-1.  To quote Wikipedia:  "Latin-1, also known as ISO-8859-1, is a similar encoding. Unicode code points 0–255 are identical to the Latin-1 values, so converting to this encoding simply requires converting code points to byte values; if a code point larger than 255 is encountered, the string can't be encoded into Latin-1."

Why did you give me a negative score?

Comment: Your experience is clearly limited. The absolute majority of external programs do not use Latin-1 by any metric I can imagine. Perhaps this was once the case in some geographies. The fact that Latin-1 is a synonym for ISO 8859-1 is true as such.

Comment: @triplee But if I'm making factual errors, I'd like to know about it.I couldn't care less about your voting.  I care about you claiming my answer is false.

Comment: So to a first approximation I would think that most Linux and Mac systems have been upgraded to use UTF-8, and most Windows systems to run whatever godforsaken code page they were configured to use. That leaves a tiny slice of legacy systems to even qualify as candidates to remain on Latin-1. If you can provide different reasoning or actual tangible numbers, I'm hoping at the very least this answer could be improved by providing either or both.

Comment: If by "most external programs" you mean PHP and MySQL, those are probably a nontrivial number of installations as such; but even then most Python programs which call an external subprocess explicitly will not be calling either of those directly. (Not my area of expertise; I believe they are both now also taking good steps to shake off their Latin-1 roots.)

Comment: Thanks, @triplee.  You are right and I am completely out of day.  I just double checked some programs that I was sure still used ISO-8859-1, and much to my surprise, they all were UTF-8.

Comment: The exposition of the mapping between Latin-1 and Unicode is also kind of misleading. It's true that the first 256 bytes of Unicode coincide with Latin-1 but the description here really doesn't do justice to the  process of converting from one to the other.